# Get exact formula used by Pytorch autograd to compute gradients

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, autograd

I am implementing a custom CNN with some custom modules in it. I have implemented only the forward pass for the custom modules and left their backward pass to autograd.
I have manually computed the correct formulae for backpropagation through the parameters of the custom modules, and I wished to see whether they match with the formulae used internally by autograd to compute the gradients.
Is there any way to see this?
Thanks

Edit (To add a test case) :-

I have a complex affine layer where the weights and inputs are complex-valued matrices, and the operation is a matrix multiplication of the weight and input matrices.
The multiplication of two complex numbers is given by -
(a+ib)(c+id) = (ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)

I computed the backpropagation formula for this layer given we have the incoming gradient from the higher layer.
It comes out to be dL/dI(n) = (hermitian(W(n))).matmul(dL/dI(n+1))
where I(n) and W(n) are the input and weight of nth layer and I(n+1) is input of (n+1)th layer.

So I wished to check whether autograd is also computing dL/dI(n) using the same formula that I derived.

(Since Pytorch doesn't support complex-valued tensors backpropagation as for now, I have created my own representation of complex numbers by dealing with separate real and imaginary tensors)

Comment: Is using test cases suitable for you?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a feature in pytorch, even because it would be quite unreadable. What you can do is to implement a custom [backward](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/defining-backward-function-in-nn-module/5047/2) method for your layer with the formula you derived, then know by design that the backpropagation is what you want.